# How to store and read integer matrix by OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to build an openCV matrix. The following is my code.

```
int data[9]={0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0};
cv::Mat m(3, 3, CV_8SC1,data);
cout<<(int)m.at<char>(0,1)<<endl;
cout<<(int)m.at<schar>(0,1)<<endl;
```

There is no result shown in my monitor. But, if I change my code to the following.

```
float data[9]={0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0};
cv::Mat m(3, 3, CV_32FC1,data);
cout<<m.at<float>(0,1)<<endl;
```

The "1" will be shown. However, if I use type "float" instead of "int", I need to spend redundant memory to store number "1", "0" or "-1". Is there any who know how to save integer with openCV? Thank you.

---

After searching more website, I found a solution as following .

```
cv::Mat C = (cv::Mat_<int>(3,3) << 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
cout << "C = " << endl << " " << C.at<int>(0,1)<<endl;
```

Comment: This looks like it should work. Do you get any error?

Comment: Why do you want to use int at all? It should need much more memory than char, you can test it with cout << sizeof(char) << " vs " << sizeof(int) <<  " vs " << sizeof(float) << std::endl;

Comment: Because the number may be larger than 256

Comment: I guess I misinterpreted your sentence `I need to spend redundant memory to store number "1", "0" or "-1"`... I thought you only want to save the values `0,1,-1` which would fit in `char` range :)  ... In fact you will spend the same amount of memory for any float (32 bit) value as for any int (32 bit) value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem seems to be your input data array type. You use an `int` (probably 32 bit) type for your array but you use `char` (8 bit) type for your matrix.

please try:

```
char data[9]={0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0};
cv::Mat m(3, 3, CV_8SC1,data);
cout<<(int)m.at<char>(0,1)<<endl;
cout<<(int)m.at<schar>(0,1)<<endl;
```

If you want or have to use the int array, try

```
int data[9]={0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0};
cv::Mat m(3, 3, CV_32SC1,data);
cout<<(int)m.at<int>(0,1)<<endl;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I can run the first answer well. But, I have a run time error when I use second case. Besides, I have find the other solution on other website and I update my question.

Comment: Problem of the 2nd version was the access in the cout, now it should work (not tested)

Comment: Oh! I know what you mean.